# add image in another folder instead of drawable in xamarin cross-platforms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am able to display image from Drawable folder by using

```
<image source="live.png"/>
```

But i don't know how to get image from other folder i create in Resource 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the image to come from? There is a way to use images from the common PCL if you're using Xamarin.Forms, but it's a little complicated. If you're looking at Android only then your images really should not live anywhere but the `Drawable` folder.

Comment: i am learning Cross-Platform xamarin

Comment: And i want to put images in other folder in Resources because i need to sort kind of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is very picky about where you can put images, so your best bet is to store your images in the common project. In this example I assume a standard Xamarin.Forms solution with the following projects: Foo, Foo.Android, Foo.IOS and Foo.UWP. Yours will obviously have different names, so you'll have to substitute the Foos...

All the following code will go into the common code project, `Foo`.

First, create a new folder called `Extensions` (just to keep your code tidy) and add the following class to it:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Now add the namespace for this class to your markup:

```
xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:Foo.Extensions"
```

Next, create a folder for your images, again in your common project, NOT in your Android project. You can create subfolders as well. Add your images and make sure that the build action for each image is set to `Embedded Resource`.

Now you can reference those images in your XAML like this:

```
<Image Source="{extensions:ImageResource Foo.Images.Subfolder.Bar.png}">
```

Note that you need to supply the full path of the image, including the project name (Foo in this case) and that folders are separated by dots, not slashes.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really helpful to me 

Comment: It would be great if you could accept this answer so that other people can see that it solved this particular problem.